# How to pass in memory json data from parent component to child component in react js and to display that in tabular form in child component

Tags: json, reactjs

You are supposed to display a Song list with the fields - movie, title, length, singer. Use multiple components to display it. You can have the following components: AllSongs, SongList.

1. " AllSongs " component should maintain the state, display a heading , numbers of songs in the JSON memory object and pass on the song data to SongList.
2. " SongList " component should display the list of songs in the form of a table

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**Parent component:**

```
const allSongs = [{ title: "Hit me baby one more time", singer: "Britney Spears" }];

// Pass all songs to the parent
<SongList songs={allSongs} />;
```

**And then have the SongList like this:**

```
return (
    <div>
        {props.songs.map((song) => {
            <div>
                <h1>{song.title}</h1>
                <h2>{song.singer}</h2>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
```